# Where should I send the POST request?

Tags: php, jquery, url-routing, phalcon

I am writing an app using the Phalcon framework for PHP and I have to implement the feature to allow users to write messages on each others walls. So with JQuery I would write:

```
function postMessage()  {
    var message = $("#messageBox").val().trim().replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
    if(message) {
        $.post("// request handler", {msg: message, wall: {{ user.id }}, 
             writer: {{ session.get('user')['id'] }})
            .done(function() {
                $("#messageBox").val('');
                alert( "Message posted" );
            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert( "Error posting message, please try again" );
            });
    }
}
```

And this script would be located in the page domain.com/user/foobar

My question is what (or rather where) should my request handler be. I've thought about it a bit and asked my friend and came up with three options:

1. Post to the same url the above script is in (Ex.
   domain.com/user/foobar)
2. Post to another url which routes to
   another action in the same controller as option 1 (Ex.
   domain.com/postmessage. Both option 1 and 2 are in the same
   controller but they are different actions)
3. Post to an API url (Ex. api.domain.com)

Some pros I thought of were:

1. Both option 1 and 2 can access the session variable, so I can check
   if the user is logged in or not. With option 3, I cannot but I can
   (unrealistically) hope no one tries to abuse the system and post
   messages with Fiddler or something by not being logged in.
2. Option 2 is a bit cleaner than option 1
3. Option 2 and 3 both provide central request handlers so if I wanted
   to implement the same message on wall writing system I would only
   have to copy the Jquery code and put it in the new view or page.
   With option 1 I have to copy the code from the user controller and
   repaste it into the controllers for each of the new pages.

Some cons I thought of were:

1. Option 2 means I have to add more routes to my router. This makes
   routing more complicated. (And maybe slower???)

( Ex.

```
// Option 1
$router->add('/user/{id}',
    array(
       'controller' => 'user',
       'action'     => 'show'
    )
);

// Option 2
$router->add('/user/post/{id}',
    array(
       'controller' => 'user',
       'action'     => 'writeMessage'
    )
);
```

)

Which way is recommended and used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep defining routes as needed.  Or define a single route and pass an extra parameter in the post request that hooks into the remote procedure.

Be cautious where the users are concerned and close any loopholes.  Think about adding a nonce.

Thanks,

C

Answer (score 2):

Never ever assume that all your users will be kind and smart, it's how people break a system. Test everything.

Usually : 1 route = 1 action
If you haven't any route for posting message, adding one is the way to go.
A route is like a simple "if" test, it'll be done in a few nanoseconds.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. While you did answer first, I had to give best answer to the other one because it offered the idea of a single route for handling all the POST requests with an extra parameter and also introduced me to the idea of a nonce. But, I also liked your answer and thanks for not letting me fall into the trap of expecting nothing fishy from my users. Have a great day!